# Static methods won't work in play controllers

Tags: playframework-2.0

I recently get started with Play. So i download 2.4.3 version from official site, and have done everything as said in firstapp tutorial. But when im runnig application and want to add some methods to the controller:

```
public static Result dummy() {
    return TODO;
}
```

rout.conf

```
GET   /        controllers.Application.dummy()
```

I'm getting error page that says :

> *value dummy is not a member of controllers.Application*

But if I delete *static* keyword from the method, everything works fine. I presume that i have to change something in **build.sbt**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed line in **build.sbt** from

> routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

to

> routesGenerator := StaticRoutesGenerator

So I can use static methods